# How can I import JSON to Google Sheets from Godot via Apps Script so my constants are in the first frozen column?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, godot4

I'm currently following this tutorial / resource:  https://github.com/amzker/Gsheet_Godot
This outputs data sent from a Godot program to a sheet that looks like this,

| GreekAlphabet | WhatHungryDogDo | BananasGoodFor | HowManyWords |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | The | Bananas | These |
| Beta | Hungry | Are | Are |
| Delta | Dog | Nice | Four |
| Gamma | Eats | Snacks | Words |

My goal is to upload data to a Google Sheet from Godot in a format that resembles this,

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **GreekAlphabet** | Alpha | Beta | Delta | Gamma |
| **WhatHungryDogDo** | The | Hungry | Dog | Eats |
| **BananasGoodFor** | Bananas | Are | Nice | Snacks |
| **HowManyWords** | These | Are | Four | Words |

The relevant apps script code is as follows:

```
function json(sheetName) {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1h_KlXz9IWt2MtQQWYUSk4FJbIr02MbfXWU3ZRqY7U3I") //CHANGE WITH YOUR SHEET ID ( see url of you sheet d/)
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  const jsonData = convertToJson(data)
  return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}
function convertToJson(data) {
  const headers = data[0]
  const raw_data = data.slice(1,)
  let json = []
  raw_data.forEach(d => {
      let object = {}
      for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        object[headers[i]] = d[i]
      }
      json.push(object)
  });
  return json
}
function doGet(params) {
  const sheetname = params.parameter.sheetname
  return json(sheetname)
}

function doPost(params) {
  const datee = params.parameter.date
  const timee = params.parameter.time
  const catee = params.parameter.cate
  const amounte = params.parameter.amount
  const desce = params.parameter.desc
  const sheetname = params.parameter.sheetname

  
  if(typeof params !== 'undefined')
  Logger.log(params.parameter);

  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1h_KlXz9IWt2MtQQWYUSk4FJbIr02MbfXWU3ZRqY7U3I") //CHANGE WITH YOUR SHEET ID ( see url of you sheet d/)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname)
  var Rowtoenter = sheet.getLastRow()+1
  sheet.appendRow([datee,timee,catee,amounte,desce])
  

/* 
  var datecol = sheet.getRange(Rowtoenter,1)
  var timecol = sheet.getRange(Rowtoenter,2)
  var catecol = sheet.getRange(Rowtoenter,3)
  var amountcol = sheet.getRange(Rowtoenter,4)
  var descol = sheet.getRange(Rowtoenter,5)
  
  datecol.setValue(datee)
  timecol.setValue(timee)
  catecol.setValue(catee)
  amountcol.setValue(amounte)
  descol.setValue(desce)
*/
  
}
```

When the data leaves Godot, it's in the form of a URL with a string of parameters appended.

> date=TODAY&time=NOW&cate=CATE&amount=AMOUNT&desc=DESC&flibble=SPONDS&sheetname=Sheet1

Once it reaches Sheets, it's converted into the first kind of table, where I really want it to appear as the second kind of table. =/

I'm trying to wade through the source and read through the Docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) but I'm very new to working with JSON and I'm finding it hard to get a starting point.

Any thoughts appreciated!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY0Yl.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kASx9.png)

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: I haven't only shared a spreadsheet/image as the only source of data - at the top of the question, there's a link to the Github page which includes the entire source code I'm working from. As far as I can tell, I'm not sharing Google files (the reason I went with images). I'll give your table link an attempt now...

Comment: Please click the first link in my comment: [spreadsheets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260453/should-using-whateverfiddle-com-as-part-of-the-question-be-discouraged/260455#260455). Github link is still external.

Comment: Roger, will attempt to cooperate. I'm not sure where I'm to use the formula described in the third link of your original comment. Will post the relevant code from the Github link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1h_KlXz9IWt2MtQQWYUSk4FJbIr02MbfXWU3ZRqY7U3I")

/** Requires sheet to already be in column-header format */
function convertToJson(data) {
  return data.flatMap(([header, ...rowData]) => ({ [header]: [...rowData] }))
}

function json(sheetName) {

  const data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange().getValues()
  const jsonData = convertToJson(data)

  return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)

}

function doGet(params) {
  return json(params.parameter.sheetname)
}

function doPost(params) {

  const { date, time, cat, amount, desc, sheetname } = params.parameter

  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  const entryColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()+1  

  const columnData = [date, time, cat, amount, desc].map(item => [item])
  sheet.getRange(1, entryColumn, columnData.length, 1).setValues(columnData)
  
}
```

---

If your sheet(s) are still in the "top row as header" format, you can run:

```
function convertSheet() {

  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`**YOUR_SHEET**`)

  const sheetValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  const convertedValues = sheetValues[0].map((_, index) => sheetValues.flatMap(row => row[index]))

  sheet.setFrozenRows(0)
  sheet.setFrozenColumns(1)

  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, convertedValues.length, convertedValues[0].length).setValues(convertedValues)

}
```